# Downloading project files form git in place induced command

Tags: linux, git, file

I have question for cloning repo with git. First of all I don't know what phrase write in google to find answer to my question.
Normally when I cloning repo I use `git clone url` and this command downloads project in folder with project name. But how I can download all project files in place that I induced git command?

I know that I can remove this manually with commands

```
$ mv /path/project_name/.[!.]* /path/ 
$ mv /path/project_name/* /path/
```

Comment: If you intend to clone in the current directory, then this should work ```git clone <repo-url> .```

Comment: Maybe I wrote it wrong. When you clone project with `git clone` you have cloned project folder in present place, but I want to download all files in present place not a folder with project files.

Comment: When you open a shell in a directory, the directory becomes the current working directory, so when you execute this ```git clone <repo-url> .``` in the shell, you are basically cloning the repository in your current working directory i.e represented by `.` (a dot) , however if you execute this ```git clone <repo-url>``` (without the dot), then that creates another directory in the name of the project and clones the repository in that directory

Comment: Oh I was thinking that dot is just finish of sentence. It was that what I was looking for.